# Falha na conversão varchar 'a vencer' para o tipo de dados int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boas!
Estou com problemas na comparação de duas datas dentro de uma query.
Como segue:

```
select (case 
      when getdate() <= datavencto Then '' 
      when datapagto <>0 Then DATEDIFF(day, datavencto, datapagto)
      else
      DATEDIFF(day, datavencto, getdate()) End) as Dias
 from financeirorecebimento
```

Na primeira instrução comparo o vencimento com a data atual e ele retorna 0 quando é atendida, mas gostaria que retornasse os dizeres "a vencer".

Se mantenho aspas Ok, mas quando coloco o texto, ele diz que teve uma falha na conversão varchar para int.

como posso tratar para que aceite esse texto 'a vencer' quando o resultado é o esperado?

obrigado.
Eduardo

Comment: tente retornar null ou zero na primeira condição: `when getdate() <= datavencto Then 0`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isso está ocorrendo pois você está misturando os tipos string e int. Quando usar o case, vc só pode ter um tipo de dado como resultado. Explanando melhor, este trecho:

```
when getdate() <= datavencto Then 'Em dia'
```

Retorna uma string com o texto 'Em dia'..

Já isso:

```
when datapagto <>0 Then DATEDIFF(day, datavencto, datapagto)
```

Retorna a quantidade de dias entre duas datas, ou seja, um número, e a menos que você o converte para string, vai dar erro, por causa da condição anterior.

Então, ou você só trabalha textos, ou só números e vai ter sucesso.

Comment: Ricardo, 
Obrigado pela analise e explicação. 
Acredito que mantendo tudo como texto, vai atender da mesma forma que era esperado.
Obrigado!
Eduardo

Comment: Poderia por gentileza marcar a resposta como útil?

Comment: Feito! Obrigado novamente.